# Overfull hbox with tabularx in book incl. minimal example

Tags: tabularx

The error: "Undefined Control Sequence. Overfull hbox (15.0pt too wide)" appears for each "end tabularx." I have tried {noindent} before \say{begintabularx} without success. While I could continue working for the first 500+ instances of this error, now the document will not render.

Error Messages https://ibb.co/5Y4DtCS

Rendered https://ibb.co/nBWSSth

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{type1cm}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\geometry{paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,inner=1in}

\usepackage{perpage}
\MakePerPage{footnote}

\usepackage{afterpage}

\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\say{Undefined Control Sequence.\\
Overfull hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 53 and 63 and 75.\\
- these are the \say{end tabularx} lines.}
\end{center}

\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth} { 
    >{\full\arraybackslash}X 
    >{\full\arraybackslash}X  }

\begin{center}
\noindent \textbf{Header Left Column}
\end{center}
 &
 \begin{center}
\noindent \textbf{Header Right Column}
\end{center}

\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth} { 
    >{\full\arraybackslash}X 
    >{\full\arraybackslash}X  }
 
\noindent \lipsum[3]
 &
\noindent \lipsum[4]

\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth} { 
    >{\full\arraybackslash}X 
    >{\full\arraybackslash}X  }
 
\noindent \lipsum[5]
 &
\noindent \lipsum[6]

\end{tabularx}

\bigskip

\noindent Why the error for \say{end tabularx?} I am using overleaf.com in Firefox 81.0 on OSX 10.15.6. I have tried {noindent} before \say{begintabularx} without success. The usecase is a polyglot book, with one language in the left column and a different language in the right column. The two columns must begin on the same line, but are not required to end on the same line.

\bigskip

\noindent Many thanks for your help.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: How or where is `\full` defined?

Answer (score 2):

> "Undefined Control Sequence. Overfull hbox (15.0pt too wide)"

These are two entirely separate issues:

- The first is that you get an error message because `\full` isn't defined. How or where is `\full` defined.
- The second is a warning message (not an error message) caused by the fact that you didn't specify `\noindent` right before `begin{tabularx}`. It's somewhat ironic that your code has lots of `\noindent` directives where they aren't needed, but is lacking the `\noindent` directives where they are needed.

The following screenshot features two identical `tabularx` environments; the only difference is that the first isn't preceded by `\noindent`. (Since I don't know how `\full` is defined, I decided to omit it from the code.) Sure enough, the first one generates a "Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines..." message whereas the second does not.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,inner=1in,nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype,tabularx}

\usepackage{booktabs,showframe,lipsum} % <-- new
\begin{document}

%\noindent % <-- "\noindent" deliberately commented out
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{@{} XX @{}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Header Left Column}  &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Header Right Column} \\
\addlinespace
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[4] 
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{0.5in}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{@{} XX @{}}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Header Left Column}  &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Header Right Column} \\
\addlinespace
\lipsum[2] & \lipsum[4] 
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This explanation of the error, and this suggested fix, were successful for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error message,

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<template> ...p \@startpbox {\TX@col@width }\full 
                                                  \arraybackslash \ignorespa...
l.53 \end{tabularx}
```

The line break shows where TeX was in parsing the line when it hit the error. In this case, the problem is that `\full` is not defined. I don't know what you expect that to do.

The `overfull \hbox` messages are referring to the table as a whole. The 15pt is coming from a paragraph indent. Wrapping the `tabularx` environments with `center` will resolve that issue.

(There were doubtless good reasons why Leslie Lamport decided that you should be able to put a `tabular` into the middle of a paragraph when he created LaTeX, but this decision has been the root of countless pain for users in the decades since. When I taught LaTeX classes back in the 80s/90s, I encouraged users to declare an `aroundtbl` environment (and also `aroundpic`) to allow consistent placement of tabular material and graphics.)